# R - Regular Expression - Match the following pattern: WhitespaceHyphenWhitespaceSingledigit

Tags: r, regex, grepl

Consider the following data structure (df):

| ID | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Example |
| 2 | Example - 1 |
| 3 | Example - 2 |
| 4 | Example - 3 |
| 5 | Example - 4 |
| 6 | Example - 5 |
| 7 | Example - NA |
| 8 | Text |
| 9 | Text - 10 |
| 10 | Text - 20 |
| 11 | Text - 30 |
| 12 | Text - 40 |
| 13 | Text - 50 |
| 14 | Text - 60 |
| 15 | Text - 70 |
| 16 | Text - 80 |
| 17 | Text - 90 |
| 18 | Text - 100 |

In the column "Text", I want to find all rows that contain the following pattern:
WhitespaceHyphenWhitespaceSingledigit

Or in other words, I want to extract the following rows:

| ID | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Example - 1 |
| 3 | Example - 2 |
| 4 | Example - 3 |
| 5 | Example - 4 |
| 6 | Example - 5 |

Currently I use the grepl()-function in combination with regular expressions. However none of my attempts like

- df[which(grepl("s{1}-\s{1}\d{1}$", df$Text)),]
- df[which(grepl("\b\s{1}-\s{1}\d{1}\b$", df$Text)),]

has worked out. Since I am a beginner in programming, I would be grateful for any advices. Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHO `\s-\s\d` should do the trick no? Give it a shot and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unlike in the example, I work with a larger dataset. I tried your solution, but it doesn't work unfortunately. As a result, I still get rows with more than one digit and also with after the hyphen like the row with the ID = 7.

Comment: you could check Tim's answer he has covered it already the answer.

Comment: I've tried, but it hasn't worked out neither. Guess I will just keep trying by myself, but I will keep you guys updated.

Comment: If you only want to use the word boundary `grepl("\\s-\\s\\d\\b", df$Text)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following regex pattern:

```
\s-\s\d(?!\d)
```

This matches a hyphen in between whitespaces, followed by a single digit which itself is followed by either a non digit character or end of the input.

Full R code:

```r
df[grepl("\\s-\\s\\d(?!\\d)", df$Text, perl=TRUE), ]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Unfortunatly it does not work. With your code, I get the error message: Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\s". If I use another escape for every escaped letter like "\\s-\\s\\d(?!\\d)", I get the following error message: Error in grepl(pattern, c(levels(x), NA_character_), ignore.case, perl,  : invalid regular expression, reason 'Invalid regexp'

Comment: Unfortunately, I only get the following error code: 
Error in grepl(pattern, c(levels(x), NA_character_), ignore.case, perl,  : 
  invalid regular expression, reason 'Invalid regexp'. Nonetheless, thanks for trying to help me out :)

Comment: We need to use `perl=TRUE`

Comment: If I set the perl parameter to TRUE, the code finally runs. Unfortunately, I still don't get the desired output. In this case, cases like ID=7 and ID=9, 10, 11, ..., 18 are still included :/

Comment: Please provide one `Text` value for which my answer is failing.  It should not be failing at all for any case.

Comment: I am very sorry, your solution does indeed work with my example df. Unfortunately, it does not work with another data frame, with which I have to work right now. In this case, it does not work and I don't really understand why.

Comment: I suggest maybe opening a new question and including sample data which explains the problem.